# Keyup() não está a funcionar?

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma função que é suposto mostrar quantos caracteres faltam para chegar ao máximo, no entanto, ele só conta após a primeira tecla ser "clickada".

Eis o meu código

```
$("#nome_event").keyup(function(){
  var count = $(this).length;
  var dif = 30 - count;
  $("#count_nome2").html(count);
  if(count < 30 ){
    $("#count_nome").html(dif);
  }
});
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Nome do Evento</label>
   <input class="form-control" id="nome_event">
   <p class="help-block"><small>[<span id="count_nome">30</span> | <span id="count_nome2">30</span> Caracteres por usar]</small></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou o `.val()` em:

```
var count = $(this).val().length;
```

```js
$("#nome_event").keyup(function(){
  var count = $(this).val().length;
  var dif = 30 - count;
  $("#count_nome2").html(count);
  if(count < 30 ){
    $("#count_nome").html(dif);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Nome do Evento</label>
   <input class="form-control" id="nome_event">
   <p class="help-block"><small>[<span id="count_nome">30</span> | <span id="count_nome2">30</span> Caracteres por usar]</small></p>
</div>
```

Ao colocar `$(this).length;` será contado apenas a quantidade de elementos com o `id` especificado, e não o tamanho `length` do seu conteúdo.

Comment: Resultou perfeitamente, mas poderia explicar o porquê de ele só resultar no primeiro?

Comment: @I_like_trains Quando vc coloca `$(this).length;` ele na verdade conta o número de elementos com a `id`, que só tem um. O `.val().length` conta o tamanho do conteúdo dentro do elemento.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: @I_like_trains Disponha, amigo!